# Base 64 Basics on conversation

Tags: java, android

Just to know the basics,

If I get a Base 64 encoded string, can I open it in any format or the format that is been encoded to?

Example; I am getting a Base64 encoded string and the format to open is PDF, does it means it only opens as a PDF format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base64 is *just* a way of representing binary data as text. That's all it is. When you've decoded it, you've got binary data. You can do anything with that that you can do with binary data. So if it's a PDF, and you open it as a PDF, that should be fine. If the binary data was originally a JPEG and you try to open it as a PDF, that clearly won't work.

Base64 itself has no concept of a filename, or a content type - that's usually added by other layers in a protocol.

Comment: Might be basics, but please.....Now the server send me the PDF content in Base 64 encoded string, could I decode the string and open it using Notepad? What is blocking to open it?

Comment: Well if it's a PDF, that's not something you can usefully open in notepad, as notepad doesn't understand PDF format...

Comment: If I conclude, whatever the string is encoded from - the output also would be the same format :).

Comment: @Sreeram: Yes. It's *just* a wrapper. Think of it as a little bit like taking a file and zipping it up - when you unzip it, you've got the same data. Except in the case of base64, we don't even know the filename - it's just the content.

Comment: Could you please let me the common usage for it? Where do people use it?

Comment: Any time you need to transfer binary data in a text format (e.g. XML)